# Multiple Step Actions on one Button Click

Tags: java, android, button, onclick, buttonclick

I am currently trying to solve a java based problem on Android Studio.
I have puzzled my head over this problem looking in many forums and webpages to not find any solution in the last two days. So I am seeking for help here now.

I have programmed a Button that when clicked causes a textview to swipe out of the screen with an animation. After that I would like the old text ("First Text") of the Textview to be replaced with another text ("New Text") appearing on the same place where the old text was. All of this should happen with only one click on the button step-after-step.

My problem with my code is that the old text is replaced by the new text first and then causes the animation.

Does anybody now a solution for this problem?

I would be really very grateful for any help!

This is my code below.

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    Animation slideleft;
    Button btn1;
    TextView txt1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first_layout);

        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);



        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                slideleft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(FirstActivity.this, R.anim.slide_left);

                txt1.startAnimation(slideleft);

                txt1.setText("New Text");

    }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use onAnimationEnd method of animation listener and change the text inside it.

```
    animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){         
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim) {
            txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
            txt1.setText("New Text");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But is it enough to just add onAnimationEnd? Because it didn't work for me. I had to integrate the whole protocoll (onAnimationStart, onAnimationRepeat and onAnimationEnd).

Answer (score 0):

you can place which event execute after the animation place your code

```
anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
    }           
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
    }           
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
     //your_code
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome. I've read about the animationlistener a lot before but seems like I integrated it the wrong way before. However, finally got it working now. I think my mistake was that I didn't include the whole protocol (animationstart, animationrepeat and animationend) but only the animationend. Thank you very much for your help!:)